# Coding Standards critique

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if SE would be the right forum for posting my code and asking for feedback if I am following the coding standards.

Regards

Comment: You could try submitting it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and saying that apex is a subset of java perhaps.

Comment: This is already on ongoing discussion here: [Appropriate Code Review Posts](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/appropriate-code-review-posts)